# How to find an element in a dict inside tuple?

Tags: python, ldap

I have made a bit of a mess, so it is the first time I try to fetch data from a Microsoft AD. I have succeeded in this, but now I want to compare the list of names in the AD with a list I have in my database. But I find it hard to just get the name of the user from the output so I can compare the two lists. So I just want to fetch data for all users in the `ad-group` `'testuser'`, `'testuser2'` for example.

**Output from ldap_result**

```
('CN=testuser,OU=Users,OU=nnittest,DC=nnittest,DC=com', {'givenName': [b'testuser'], 'sAMAccountName': [b'testuser']})
('CN=testuser2,OU=Users,OU=nnittest,DC=nnittest,DC=com', {'givenName': [b'testuser2'], 'sAMAccountName': [b'testuser2']})
```

**Code and connection**

```
LDAP_SERVER = 'ldap://****' 
BASE_DN = 'OU=test,dc=test,dc=com' #base dn to search in
LDAP_LOGIN = 'Admin' 
LDAP_PASSWORD = '*****' 

connect = ldap.initialize(LDAP_SERVER) 
connect.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0) # to search the object and all its descendants
connect.simple_bind_s(LDAP_LOGIN, LDAP_PASSWORD)

myfilter = "memberOf=CN=nn-aws-aurora-users,OU=Groups,OU=test,DC=test,DC=com"
attrs = ['sAMAccountName', 'givenname', 'sn', 'mail', 'description', 'telephonenumber', 'homephone', 'mobile']
ldap_result = connect.search_s(BASE_DN, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, myfilter, attrs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, the result is a *tuple* and the *tuple*'s second element is a *dict*. So firstly you should get the second element of the *tuple* with `ldap_result[1]` and then you should access to the `givenName` field of *dict*.

So if you combine all of these:

`ldap_result[1]["givenName"]` will return the list of users.